# Eclipse dynamic web project : where should I put resource files

Tags: java, eclipse, inputstream

I am trying to make a eclipse dynamic web project. I have tried putting a pdf file in the "WEB-INF" directory of the project. But when I try to obtain a input stream using

`InputStream inStream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/mypdf.pdf");`

I get `inStream = null`. I also tried putting the `mypdf.pdf` file in the directory the class from where I am trying to obtain the input stream and use

`InputStream inStream = getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("mypdf.pdf");`

again, it returns `inStream = null`

Any suggestion?

Comment: @nazar_art: that's precisely what the OP should not use.

Comment: The first one should work fine. Make sure you don't have a case problem. And make sure the file is indeed in the deployed webapp.

Comment: Actually I have a shabby idea regarding this. I tried putting it in the "/WEB-INF/" inside my Eclipse project. Shouldn't eclipse include all files in that directory during deployment?

Comment: It should, if you're talking about the right WEB-INF directory.

Comment: Well, the problem still persists. I tried the suggestions on the answers before, but nothing seems to work

Comment: Post a screenshot of your eclipse project tree (with the pdf file appearing, of course).

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("mypdf.pdf");
```

if the file is in directory where your class is.

Comment: I am actually confused about this. "directory where your class is" - does it mean the .java directory or the .class directory?

Comment: you put it where .java files are. you generally don't put anything where .class files are because that is done by compiler. if you have java class in org/someorg/app/AwesomeClass.java you should put mypdf.pdf in org/someorg/app directory and then call above code from AwesomeClass

Answer (score 0):

getResourceAsStream searches for the file on the classpath

```
   InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("your pdf file");
```

Comment: I have tried your method putting the pdf file in the same directory as the class in Eclipse project src directory(containing java source codes), build directory(containing compiled classes) and at `(EclipseWorkspace).metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\MyWebApp\WEB-INF\classes\` directory. Still `stream = null` every time